# How block all iframes with exceptions?

Tags: javascript, iframe, userscripts

I want to block iframes on all sites using Greasy Monkey's UserScript. I use a script like this:

```
// @match        *://*/*
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
  var i;
  var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
  var numIframes = iframes.length;
  for (i = 0; i < numIframes; i += 1) {
    iframes[i].style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

My problem, how to make exception on certain URL? e.g. hCaptcha.com, ReCaptcha, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix would be to just check the URL in the script itself.

```
if (!(window.location.href.indexOf("Captcha") > -1)) {
//your code  
}
```

Comment: Work only reCaptcha from Google... byt won't work with, hCaptcha, SloveMedia, 2Captcha and others